# Get python variables from execute line (in bash)

Tags: bash, unix

I execute python script by using bash script, it works fine. However I'm trying to find a way to get variable (for bash usage) from python execute. Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
 python Script.py Michael 17
 python Script.py Andrea 19
 echo "Script was executed with : Michael, 17 "
 echo "Script was executed with : Andrea 19"
```

Is there any way to get that variables ? I would like to avoid assigning eg. Michael, 17 to bash variables at the beginning.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please review the guidelines on making a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consider editing your question to add enough material that someone wishing to help can be confident their answer produces the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can define arguments and pass these args to both  as below;

```
#!/bin/sh
declare -a args1
declare -a args2

args1=("Michael" "17")
args2=("Andrea" "19")

python Script.py "${args1[@]}"
python Script.py "${args2[@]}"
echo "Script was executed with : ${args1[*]}"
echo "Script was executed with : ${args2[*]}"
```

Comment: Hi, Honestly I thought about some other soultion. I would like to get access to variables separately. What if I would like to display only "Michael" instead of "Michael 17". My question was only an example.

Comment: `${args1[0]}` is "Michael".